# Pandas groupby to get dataframe of unique values

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

If I have this simple dataframe, how do I use groupby() to get the desired summary dataframe?
Using Python 3.8

**Inputs**

```
x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4]
y = [100,100,100,101,102,102,102,102,103,103,104,104,104]
z = [1,2,3,1,1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y, z)), columns =['id', 'set', 'n']) 
display(df)
```

[image]

**Desired Output**

[image]

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['id', 'set'])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby and explode

```
df.groupby('id')['set'].unique().explode()

id
1    100
2    101
2    102
3    103
4    104
```

Comment: this produces a series, not dataframe, correct?

Comment: @AlexS1 Yes, that is correct. If you want a frame then add `.to_frame().reset_index()`

Comment: @AlexS1 , you should use `reset_index()` or just `to_frame()` if you want `id` to be the index of the data frame

Answer (score 3):

With `df.drop_duplicates`

```
df.drop("n",1).drop_duplicates(['id','set'])

    id  set
0    1  100
3    2  101
4    2  102
8    3  103
10   4  104
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `.explode()` and then reset the index of the result:

```py
> df.groupby('id')['set'].unique().explode().reset_index(name='unique_value')
   id   unique_value
0   1            100
1   2            101
2   2            102
3   3            103
4   4            104
```